# Symfony: Can not create new project from other than Symfony Drive

Tags: symfony

My setup:

- Windows 10
- Symfony installed in C:\Program Files\Symfony
- PHP in C:\xampp\php

My project shall reside in:

- D:\SymfonyProjects

Then I try to create a project as follows:

- open a command shell and cd to D:\SymfonyProjects
- then I type: `symfony new TestProject`

... and get the following errors, probably because I am working from drive D: ?

> exit status 4294967294
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\bz2 (The specified module could not be found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_bz2.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\curl (The specified module could not be found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\fileinfo (The specified module could not be found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_fileinfo.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic

Question: Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible to work from drive D:\ if Symfony and PHP are on drive C:?

Comment: From the down votes I understand that something is not clear or people think that I did not research. So my clear question:

"Is it possible to work from drive D:\ if Symfony and PHP are on drive C:?"

My research for "symfony path to php" did not give any helpful results. Also I searched for "drive missing from path" - no help. 

If anyone has any idea for me to do more research or what additional information I could give I am more than willing to provide it.

Comment: How is the given error message related to Symfony after all? Why not check whether it would run on C instead (I assume: no)?

Comment: I though that an error message which appears after typing

''symfony new TestProject''

is actually related to Symfony or Symfony CLI respectively. If that assumption is wrong please correct me.

I have tried running that same command while on C: and it works. This lead me to the assumption that the error is caused by Symfony (or Symfony CLI) looking on the wrong (relative) path.

Instead of looking for PHP in C:\xampp\php Symfony (or Symfony CLI) seems to look in \xampp\php. So Symfony seems to ignore the drive letter.

Bug in Symfony (or Symfony CLI) or is it a missing config?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Have you checked whether the files that are requested (`c:\xampp\php\ext\php_bz2.dll`) do exist? And no, these errors are not related to Symfony itself, as PHP throws these errors

Answer (score 1):

Nico Haase pointed me to the right direction by writing that the error message is not generated by Symfony but by PHP. Reason was wrong path to extensions in php.ini.

Path was: `extension_dir="\xampp\php\ext"`

after changing that to `extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"`

PHP and creating new Symfony projects work.